# Transform PySpark DataFrame into a nested structure

Tags: json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm learning `PySpark`. I load a `CSV` file into a `Spark DataFrame`. After that I do some data transformation. Finally, I want some set of columns to be put into a nested structure and then save it in `JSON` format.

This is the sample code that I have:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([("Bilbo Baggins",  50), ("Gandalf", 32), ("Thorin", 19), 
                                ("Balin", 18), ("Kili", 37),("Dwalin", 19), ("Oin", 46), 
                                ("Gloin", 28), ("Fili", 22)], ["name", "age"])

mod_df = df.select(struct([col(x) for x in df.columns[:]]).alias("PersonalDetails"))
```

When I save this as a JSON file, it looks like:

```
{
        "PersonalDetails" :
                {
                        "name" : "Balin",
                        "age" : 18
                }
}
{
        "PersonalDetails" :
                {
                        "name" : "Gloin",
                        "age" : 28
                }
}
```

As you can see, they come up as separate documents. However I want them to come up in a single document with array format, like:

```
{
        "PersonalDetails" :[
                {
                        "name" : "Balin",
                        "age" : 18
                },
                {
                        "name" : "Gloin",
                        "age" : 28
                }
        ]
}
```

Can you guys help me in where I'm doing it wrong? Thank you :)

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, this is expected behaviour. You could alter your resulting json file in regular python afterwards perhaps?

Comment: No I don't want to do that. Writing huge size of data into file system and then loading them up again separately and performing further transformations sound unnecessary. Can I, in anyway, achieve my goal with Spark's other functionalities ?

Answer (score 2):

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

mod_df = df.select(
    F.struct(df.columns).alias('PersonalDetails')
).select(
    F.collect_list('PersonalDetails').alias('PersonalDetails')
)
```

Comment: This works as produces the expected output. I have one question though, I know `collect()` is a costly operation in `Spark`. Is `collect_list()` also costly?

Comment: @SivaprasannaSethuraman `collect_list` is a SQL operation, and `collect` is a spark action. `collect` is not really "expensive", it simply causes spark to execute the SQL / pipeline. It's possible that `collect_list` is expensive SQL operation to run, but it's a totally different kind of operation compared to `collect`.